# SVN path authentication using Windows domain groups

Tags: windows, apache, svn

How do you configure SVN served by Apache on Windows such that paths within a repository can have access control configured using Windows domain groups?

Comment: That's definitely belongs to ServerFault. http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/svn?sort=votes&pagesize=15

Answer (score 1):

After some research I think I've worked out how to do this using mod_sspi and a series of Apache Location configuration directives.

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath "D:/SvnRepos"
    SVNListParentPath On

    AuthType SSPI
    AuthName "SVN Server"
    SSPIAuth On
    SSPIAuthoritative On
    SSPIDomain MYDOMAIN
    SSPIOfferBasic On
    Require group MYDOMAIN\PRODUCT1_DEVS MYDOMAIN\PRODUCT2_DEVS
</Location>


<Location /svn/Repo/Product1>
    AuthType SSPI
    AuthName "SVN Product1"
    SSPIAuth On
    SSPIAuthoritative On
    SSPIDomain MYDOMAIN
    SSPIOfferBasic On
    Require group MYDOMAIN\PRODUCT1_DEVS
</Location>


<Location /svn/Repo/Product2>
    AuthType SSPI
    AuthName "SVN Product2"
    SSPIAuth On
    SSPIAuthoritative On
    SSPIDomain MYDOMAIN
    SSPIOfferBasic On
    Require group MYDOMAIN\PRODUCT2_DEVS
</Location>
```

Downsides of this approach are that configuration wise it's a bit verbose and it doesn't work for WebSVN. The first of those I don't care about and the second one I might have a look at fixing later.

A question for all you Apache and SVN experts though. Is this configuration safe and robust? It seems to work ok to me, but I haven't seen this approach mentioned anywhere else so I'm a bit nervous about deploying it without some expert feedback, and we have no experienced Apache guys inhouse.

=== EDIT ===

Ultimately I decided to set up a separate repository for each project that required specific access rights using configuration similar to this.

```
# Publishes repository 1 at url http://localhost/svn/Repo1 used mostly by team 1.
<Location /svn/Repo1>
    # DAV config.
    DAV svn

    # Config to publish single repository.
    SVNPath "D:/SvnRepos/Repo1"

    # Config to publish all repositories in directory.
    #SVNParentPath "D:/SvnRepos/"
    #SVNListParentPath On

    # Auth config.
    AuthName "SVN"
    AuthType SSPI
    SSPIAuth On
    SSPIOfferBasic On
    SSPIAuthoritative On

    <RequireAny>
        # Allows access to any user.
        #Require valid-sspi-user

        # Allows access to users belonging to specified domain group(s).
        Require sspi-group DOMAIN_NAME\TEAM1

        # Allows access to specified domain users.
        Require sspi-user DOMAIN_NAME\user1
    </RequireAny>

</Location>

# Publishes repository 2 at url http://localhost/svn/Repo2 used by several teams.
<Location /svn/Repo2>
    # DAV config.
    DAV svn

    # Config to publish single repository.
    SVNPath "D:/SvnRepos/Repo2"

    AuthName "SVN"
    AuthType SSPI
    SSPIDomain DOMAIN_NAME
    SSPIAuth On
    SSPIOfferBasic On
    SSPIAuthoritative On

    Require sspi-group DOMAIN_NAME\TEAM1 DOMAIN_NAME\TEAM2 DOMAIN_NAME\TEAM3
</Location>
```

I do wonder though whether my original configuration might have worked if I had of just removed the first location element giving access to the root /svn directory, I'm sure I must have tested that but don't have time to verify this now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Apache to use LDAP/AD for authentication and you have to configure the [path-base-authorization within SVN Repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz.perdir) to define the [permissions within](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz) the repository.

Comment: I'm using mod_auth_sspi to provide AD based authentication, but as far as I've been able to find out it doesn't support speciying access by domain groups in AuthzSVNAccessFile, although if anyone knows different I'd love to hear about it.